# Passing parameters to a method - UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to pass a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` parameter to the  `onCViewPanned` from `showFollowing` method.

I tried to pass `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` but, it didn't take it. How can i solve this ?

```
-(void) showFollowing{
    [self onCViewPanned: ??????];
}

- (void)onCViewPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture {



    // do something

}
```

Comment: Are you using that parameter inside that method ?

Comment: You check the recognizer's states (usually in a switch statement) inside the recognizer's action method. You don't pass a state in; that makes no sense, so you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Subclass the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and add property, like answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom UIPanGestureRecognizer like this

```
// MYPanGestureRecognizer.h

@interface MYPanGestureRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *data;

@end


// MYPanGestureRecognizer.m

@implementation MYPanGestureRecognizer

@end

// =================   
...

MYPanGestureRecognizer *panObj = [[MYPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];

panObj.datas = @"Hello";



// ====================
-(void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer {

MYPanGestureRecognizer *pan = (MYPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer;

NSLog(@"data : %@", pan.data);
}
```

Hope it's help you ...

Comment: I want to pass `panObj  ` to `-(void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer ` as a parameter . How can i do it ? for example like `[self panDetected:panObj];`

Comment: Did you try -(void)panDetected:(MYPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer

Comment: `MYPanGestureRecognizer *panObj = [[MYPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
` doesn't call `panDetected ` . Help.

Comment: can you please explain deeply !